# Get selected list of columns from JSON Array field

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-11

I have the following table with sample data:

**Table**:

```
create table tbl_jtest
(
    jdata json
);

insert into tbl_jtest values
('[{"fdate":"2021-01-01","name":"John","add1":"UK"},{"name":"Sam"},{"fdate":"2020-12-12","number":89789}]'),
('[{"name":"Jack","add2":"US","number":12302}]'),
('[{"fdate":"2011-02-11","name":"Lee"},{"number":785412}]'),
('[{"fdate":"2021-06-05","name":"Smith"},{"fdate":"2015-12-10","name":"Will"},{"name":"Jazz","number":556644}]');
```

I have the list of input columns which needs to be selected from JSON Array column `jdata`.

Given list of columns(maybe one or many):

List of columns: `fdate,name,number`

**Expected output**:

```
jdata
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"fdate":"2021-01-01","name":"John"},{"name":"Sam"},{"fdate":"2020-12-12","number":89789}]
[{"name":"Jack","number":12302}]
[{"fdate":"2011-02-11","name":"Lee"},{"number":785412}]
[{"fdate":"2021-06-05","name":"Smith"},{"fdate":"2015-12-10","name":"Will"},{"name":"Jazz","number":556644}]
```

Comment: @S-Man, `add1` and `add2` columns are there in JSON array please check. Which should not be in output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8378b9d2676813381da6dd3bcbb76712)

```
SELECT
    id,
    json_agg(new_object)                                                   -- 5
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        json_object_agg(elems.key, elems.value) as new_object              -- 4
    FROM tbl_jtest,
        json_array_elements(jdata) WITH ORDINALITY a_elems(value, index),  -- 1 
        json_each(a_elems.value) elems                                     -- 2
    WHERE elems.key IN ('fdate', 'name', 'number')                         -- 3
    GROUP BY id, a_elems.index
) s
GROUP BY id
```

You need to extract and expand the entire JSON object, to check the key strings and reaggregate the filtered records again:

1. Extract the arrays into one records per JSON object. The `WITH ORDINALITY` adds an index to be able to identify the correct elements later on reaggregation.
2. Extract the elements of each JSON object into one row. This creates the columns `key` and `value`
3. Filter the relevant key strings
4. Rebuild the JSON objects with the remaining `key`/`value` pairs
5. Reaggregate them into a new JSON array.